# WebAPI EF update 30,000 rows of data is very slow

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to have my asp.net WebAPI web service read a `.csv` and update a database using Entity Framework. The `.csv` file is about 20,000-30,000 rows.

As of now I am using a `TextfieldParser` to read the `.csv`, each row of the `.csv` file I create a new object, then add object to the EF context.

Once it's done adding all rows to the context, then I call `db.SaveChanges();`

Watching the console I noticed it calls an update statement for each row... which takes a long time. Is there a better more efficient way to accomplish this?

```
if (filetype == "xxx")
{
    using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(downloadFolder + fileName))
    {
        csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
        csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

        int rowCount = 1;

        while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
        {
            string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();

            //skip header row
            if (rowCount != 1)
            {                           
                var t = new GMI_adatpos
                        {
                            PACCT = fieldData[3]
                        };

                db.GMI_adatpos.Add(t);
            }

            rowCount++;
        }
    }
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Update statements? This should generate insert statements. And what is "a long time"? You won't get it in the wink of an eye. What did you expect realistically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is very common,

In your case, we can split it into two category:

- Add vs AddRange Performance
- Write & database round-trip

**Add vs AddRange Performance**

The Add method will try to detect change every time you add a new record while the AddRange only does it once. Detecting changes every time can take several minutes.

This issue is very easy to fix, simply create a list, add the entity to this list instead and use AddRange with the list at the end.

```
List<GMI_adatpo> list = new List<GMI_adatpo>();

if (filetype == "xxx")
{
    using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(downloadFolder + fileName))
    {
        csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
        csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

        int rowCount = 1;

        while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
        {
            string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();

            //skip header row
            if (rowCount != 1)
            {                           
                var t = new GMI_adatpos
                        {
                            PACCT = fieldData[3]
                        };

                list.Add(t);
            }

            rowCount++;
        }
    }
}

db.GMI_adatpos.AddRange(list)
db.SaveChanges();
```

**Write & Database round-trip**

Everytime you save a record, you perform a database round-trip. So if you insert average 30,000 record, you perform 30,000 database round-trip which is insane!

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

This library allows to perform:

- BulkSaveChanges
- BulkInsert
- BulkUpdate
- BulkDelete
- BulkMerge

You can either call BulkSaveChanges instead of SaveChanges or create a list to insert and use directly BulkInsert instead for even more performance.

BulkSaveChanges Solution (Way faster than SaveChanges)

```
db.GMI_adatpos.AddRange(list)
db.SaveChanges();
```

BulkInsert Solution (Fastest than BulkSaveChanges but do not save related entities)

```
db.BulkInsert(list);
```

Comment: thanks Jonathan... the list reduced the processing time about 30-40%, your project EntityFrameworkExtension reduced the time about 90-95%.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Because the number of items added to the DbContext is very high, ram space is gradually filled, and operation is very slow. Therefore is better that after a few records (ex 100), calling SaveChanges Methods and renew DbContext.

```
if (filetype == "xxx")
{
    using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(downloadFolder + fileName))
    {
        csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
        csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

        int rowCount = 1;

        while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
        {
            if(rowCount%100 == 0)
            {
                db.Dispose();
                db.SaveChanges();
                db = new AppDbContext();//Your DbContext
            }

            string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();

            //skip header row
            if (rowCount != 1)
            {                           
                var t = new GMI_adatpos
                        {
                            PACCT = fieldData[3]
                        };

                db.GMI_adatpos.Add(t);
            }

            rowCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you Mohammad, this reduced the time about 30-40%